# Displaying polygon feature as point symbol in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, symbology, point

I am working with a layer where a feature comprises rectangles and circles and has been created as polygons by tracing aerial imagery.  The size of the feature is defined in the attributes.

Is it possible to display the feature as a point symbol in ArcMap (with attributes defining its size and shape) instead of the polygon shape.

The traced polygons contain minor errors or issues, such as incorrect size, a circle is shown as a series of lines or rectangles dont have right angles.

Comment: You could make the polygons invisible (transparency) and just use labels.Labels can be set to space more widely for wider features; this is just one way to get size across without showing the actual shapes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Representations](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/what-are-representations-.htm) to do that. I can't give you much details because I've only looked into representation once, years ago. One of it's features is that the representation geometry can be different from the original.

There are some limitations, e.g. AFAIK representations cannot be used in ArcGIS Server, and they are (or can be) slower than traditional symbols.

Obviously, the alternative is to create a point featureclass first.